# How can I handle the identical SEOmatic config for multi-sites?

Tags: craft3, multi-site, plugin-seomatic

I'm using the amazing SEOmatic plugin in a multi-site config in craft 3.

I have a total of 18 sites and they share a lot of identical data. So I was wondering if it was possible to export the configuration I made for the main site and import it to the others.

Is there a way to avoid configuring 18x the same thing? It will save me a bunch of time.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So check out this issue for ways I'm thinking about tackling this problem; any input from you would be welcome: https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-seomatic/issues/227

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I'll try to copy the seomatic_metabundles table for now but the idea of having a master site than can be overridden sounds great.